# Ruby on Rails send_file not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In views:  `<%= link_to "save", download_user_path(1) %>`

In controller:

```
def download
    send_file "#{Rails.root}/public/data/data.csv", type: "text/csv", :disposition => 'attachment'
end
```

In routes:

```
resources :users do
 member do
  get "download"
 end
end
```

The hyperlink "save" does not work, and it shows the content of CSV file in the browser when clicking the "save" button. However, the file could be downloaded by using the URL("http://localhost:3000/users/1/download") in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try add it:

> send_file 'path_to_file', :type=>"type", :x_sendfile=> true

Or:

> %= link_to your_button_name, your_path, download: true %

Or:

> %= link_to your_button_name, your_path, download: '' %